# XSLT for XML to XML Conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a requirement where an XML document needs to have more than one language values in it. some of them being hebrew/ arabic.

I am trying to convert XML using XSLT so that the direction of the phrases can be changed in display or anything which uses it.
below is an example of the format we have.

```
<booklet>
<page><Short_name> IL</Short_name>
<Phrase>Arabic words 1</Phrase>
<Phrase>Arabic words 2</Phrase>
<Pagebreak> </Pagebreak>
</page><page><Short_name></Short_name>
<Phrase>english words 1</Phrase>
<Phrase>english words 2</Phrase>
<Phrase>english words 3</Phrase>
<Phrase>english words 4</Phrase>
</page></booklet>
```

below is the XSLT file i am looking as a start

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <booklet>
      <xsl:for-each select="booklet/page">
        <page>
          <xsl:element name="Short_name">
            <xsl:value-of select="Short_name"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:for-each select="Phrase">
            <Phrase>
              <xsl:value-of select="@Phrase"/>
            </Phrase>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:element name="Pagebreak">
            <xsl:value-of select="Pagebreak"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </page>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </booklet>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this does not render the value of the Phrase tag and always display null. not sure what is the error here.

i also need help on setting the direction attribute to RTL for the pharse which has arabic value in it, i can detect them by using the short name value, but not sure on how to set the direction attribute in XSLT.

the expected results are shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<booklet xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <page>
    <Short_name>IL</Short_name>
    <Phrase>זהו מבחן עברי 1</Phrase>  **---- This phrase needs to be RTL**
    <Phrase>זהו מבחן עברי 2</Phrase>  ---- This phrase needs to be RTL
    <Phrase>זהו מבחן עברי 3</Phrase>  ---- This phrase needs to be RTL
    <Phrase>english wording 2 test</Phrase>  ---- This phrase needs to be LTR
    <Pagebreak> </Pagebreak>
  </page>
  <page>
    <Short_name></Short_name>
    <Phrase>English test 1</Phrase>   ---- This phrase needs to be LTR
    <Phrase>English test 2</Phrase>  ---- This phrase needs to be LTR
  </page>
</booklet>
```

Comment: Can you also write the expected output of your transform for the given input?

Comment: I don't see how the given input can produce the given output - where does the arabic come from? And are you actually looking for FO advice or for XSL advice?

Comment: i am not sure on how to achieve this, i am pretty new to XSL. the data comes from a oracle database which is pulled by .Net app and XML is generated. the target is to have XML in Visual order(RTL for ARabic/ Hebrew) rather than logical order ( LTR always). i was able to get the website UI produce desired output but not in XML.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question because you fail to ask the question clearly. While I understand that you're new to this technology and thus maybe not familiar with the terms, I asked multiple times for a matching set of input and output in order to understand what you actually want to do but what you have provided is obvisouly not matching together.

Comment: Hi Lucero, whenever you write something to XML using XML data writer the default OS settings and default Oracle stored data will handle the direction in which it has to be written. for us the OS is set to American and  Oracle stores data in LTR order. which means that the words in English and Arabic are all written to XML in left to right Order. is there a way either in C# or XSL to change the direction of some of the words ( can be filtered by XML elements ) to set the direction property to Right to Left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the expected output is (especially also in regards to RTL), but the problem with the `Phrase` is that you're iterating on it and then trying to read its value as attribute (which is is not).

The following change produces the phrases:

```
      <xsl:for-each select="Phrase">
        <Phrase>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Phrase>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you. that helped me.
the RTL is for setting the direction property. in CSS it is set as 
   direction: rtl;
   unicode-bidi: embed;

i can see that the xsl:fo has some formatting options as descried in W3 schools

Comment: Note that the Formatting Objects (XSL-FO) is just one possible output of the Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformation (XSLT). As far as your example goes it only transforms to plain XML, and not FO (namespaced `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format`). It's still not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Lucero, the target is to have some phrase elements in RTL direction and some in LTR using XSL or any other technology available for XML.